# Auto format a file to print in Vim

Tags: vim, printing, formatting

Sometimes I work with a file that contains source code, columns, plain text, sometimes all 3. It looks great on the screen. However, when I send it to a printer, it comes out a mess: columns/tables are misalignment, code looks like a spaghetti, etc.

I use Vim (7.2). How do I reformat the file to please the printer?

Perhaps I should shorten the length of a line?

Comment: I never encountered any problems with printing regarding misalignment, spaghetti-looks and such. Could you give an example of the problem ?

Comment: Also, do try to keep the lines within 80 or 72 character limit. There are good reasons for doing so, and it will save you much trouble later (even in printing).

Comment: Thomas, obviously, code printed out in proportional font is normally misaligned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How do you send it to printer? Try `:hardcopy` command.

You can also lookup printing-related options `printfont`, `printdevice`, `printoptions`, etc.

See also [printoptions and others on vimdoc.sourceforge.net](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'printoptions')

Comment: Then really do try `:hardcopy` from `vim`. you can try `hardcopy>file.ps` first to preview.

Comment: How do I use printfont, printdevice, printoptions?

Comment: `:help printfont`, `:help printdevice`, `:help printoptions`.

Comment: First, I suggest that you install `vim` with help files. It sounds like you need it. Second, check this out: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'printoptions'

Answer (score 1):

It's not a pure-Vim solution, but I've had good experiences with [GNU `a2ps`](http://www.infres.enst.fr/~demaille/) for converting (relatively) poorly formatted text documents (a couple Project Gutenberg titles, to be specific) to a nice, printable pdf/postscript file.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't worried about having to have a one-step process with no intermediary between Vim and the printer, here is a fairly flexible strategy.

1. If you have a dark background in Vim with light foreground but would like to print black-on-white since white-on-black is great for terminals but not so great for printed media, try `colorscheme shine`. (Another nice colorscheme for this is [Hemisu](https://github.com/noahfrederick/vim-hemisu), which is superior to Shine for printing diffs.)
2. Use `:TOhtml` to convert the document to HTML.
3. Save the file and open it in your browser.
4. Open print preview from your browser and set up the window appropriately.

   - For example, I just printed a nearly 200 column file brought in from Vim this way, and it worked out fine (both in the sense of "well" and in the sense of "small print" :) because I was able to use Firefox's print preview to set the file to print in landscape mode.
5. Print the file from your browser.

Answer (score 0):

I agree there is a problem. yim has 'formatoptions' to 'wrap' lines together the way you want and break lines at appropriate places ('linebreak', 'breakat') which would give you an elementary wysiwyg word-processing capability, except that it only works on the display and has no effect when sent off to print.

Comment: you're talking about softwrap, but Vim has hardwrap, too. `=` command I think (I'd have to look it up).